# Returning a struct datatype in C error message

Tags: c, struct, arguments, return

See my previous post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548828/trying-to-save-command-line-arguments-in-a-dynamic-array-in-c

So, I want to return a char* array and the total number of elements in it. I couldn't figure a way out to get the total number of elements directly as I am unaware if I can just iterate through the array and stop when found NULL, is that possible? I mean does it give a NULL value if it reaches out of bounds of the arrray?
Otherwise I tried to create a struct as follows: struct name_vertex which has two variables a char** vertex_name and int curr_size and changed the code according and I get an error message 
**"expected =, ,, ;, asm or __attribute__ before unique_name**" I don't understand what that means..and I checked my .h file and I am not missing any ; or , or =.

```
name_vertex* unique_name(char *argv[], int argc)
     {
       int i, j, curr_max, index, counter, flag;
       char *temp;
       name_vertex* structure_p;

       /*
    *Allocating of size 4 char*. Trying to make it a string pointer array
    *Not sure if this is the correct way
    */  
       structure_p= malloc(4*sizeof(name_vertex));
       /*
    *Setting the first two elements of the allocation to 
        *the second and third element of the command line argv 
    *as you may know, the first one is the file name
    */
       structure_p.vertex_name[0] = argv[1];
       structure_p.vertex_name[1] = argv[2];
       index=2;  //Index variable for the dynamic array
       curr_max = 3;   //current total number of elements, 1 < total allocated as array element count starts at 0
       structure_p.curr_size = 4;  //Allocation amount int literal, count starts at 1

       /*
    *The outer loops starts at four as it is for the argv[] and the first one is irrelevent
    *The outer loop essentially jumps 3 elements at a time as 
    *I am ultimately going to use this for a graph data structure that 
    *I am trying to create. So this array will store all the unique names of vertices
    *so it makes setting the names when creating  vertices easy
    * Also will tell me how many unique vertices to create.
    *The inner loop only runs once and it checks if there is a name that alreaady exist.
    *It only takes into cosideration the first 2 out of the 3 that are considered in the outer loop
    *The the third one is going to be an integer value for the edge weight of two vertices 
    *so don't need it right now
    */
       for(i=4; i<argc; i+=3)
     {
       for(j=0; j<1; j++)
         {
               flag = 0;
           counter = 0;

           //Compare first argv[i] with all the elements
           //of vertex_name array
           while(counter<index)
         {
           if(strcmp(argv[i], stucture_p.vertex_name[counter]) == 0)
             {
               flag = 1;
               break;
             }
           counter++;
         }
           //If no match found, allocates some memory
           //adds the element to vertex_name
           //Increments index, curr_size, curr_max
           if(flag == 0)
             {
           temp = realloc(structure_p, (structure_p.curr_size + 2) * sizeof(name_vertex)); //CHECK THE SYNTAX, WANNA ADD 2 MORE ELEMENTS TO ARRAY
           structure_p = temp;
           structure_p.vertex_name[index] = argv[i];
           index++;
           structure.curr_size +=2;
           curr_max +=2;
         }

           flag = 0;   //reset flag
           counter = 0; //reset counter

           //Do the same comparison as above, but
           //this time its argv[i+1] compared
           while(counter < index)
         {
           if(strcmp(argv[i+1], structure_p.vertex_name[j]) ==0)
             {
               flag = 1;
               break;
             }
           counter++;
         }
           //If no match found, same process as before
           //Increment index, curr_size, curr_max variables
         if(flag == 0)
           {
             temp = realloc(structure.vertex_name, (structure.curr_size + 2) * sizeof(name_vertex)); //CHECK THE SYNTAX, WANNA ADD 2 MORE ELEMENTS TO ARRAY
             structure_p.vertex_name = temp;
             structure_p.vertex_name[index] = argv[i+1];
             index++;
             structure_p.curr_size += 2;
             curr_max +=2;
           }

         }
     }
       //Returning the new array
       return structure_p;
     }
```

Comment: is the name_vertex type defined anywhere? Also try to keep the code concise (meaning no 10 line chunks of comments).

Comment: It's best that you trim down the code in your questions to the absolute minimum that is sufficient to reproduce the problem, especially a compilation problem. Someone has to read your stuff. Don't overload them with unnecessary things.

Answer (score 0):

`name_vertex` is probably undefined or defined differently from how you are trying to use it.

Option 1:

```
typedef struct
{
  // yada, yada, yada
} name_vertex;

name_vertex unique_name(/*etc*/)
{
  // ...
  name_vertex structure;
  // ...
  return structure;
}
```

Option 2:

```
struct name_vertex
{
  // yada, yada, yada
};

struct name_vertex unique_name(/*etc*/)
{
  // ...
  struct name_vertex structure;
  // ...
  return structure;
}
```

Option 3:

```
typedef struct name_vertex
{
  // yada, yada, yada
} name_vertex;

name_vertex unique_name1(/*etc*/)
{
  // ...
  name_vertex structure;
  // ...
  return structure;
}

struct name_vertex unique_name2(/*etc*/)
{
  // ...
  struct name_vertex structure;
  // ...
  return structure;
}
```

As for iterating over an array with a pointer, when your pointer goes outside of the array boundaries, it does not become `NULL`. You either have to know the array size or the pointer to its first or last element (whichever is appropriate) or the array itself must contain a special value in its first/last element, so you know when you have finished processing the array. No magic. You have to manage your pointers and array indices yourself.

Answer (score -1):

C does not support returning complex data types from functions. Instead, you need to pass in a pointer to the already-allocated structure and have the function fill it in, or have the function return a newly-allocated pointer.

Option 1:

```
void unique_name(char *argv[], int argc, name_vertex* structure_p) {
  // fill structure_p using structure_p->field = value.
}
// In the caller:
name_vertex* structure_p = malloc(sizeof(name_vertex));
unique_name(argv, argc, structure_p);
// use structure_p
free(structure_p);
```

Option 2:

```
name_vertex* unique_name(char *argv[], int argc) {
  // ...
  name_vertex* structure_p = malloc(sizeof(name_vertex));
  // fill structure_p using structure_p->field = value.
  return structure_p;
}

// In the caller:
name_vertex* structure_p = unique_name(argv, argc);
// use structure_p
free(structure_p);
```

Comment: `C does not support returning complex data types from functions.` Rally? [How about this?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12542058/968261).

Comment: -1 You can return any type you like from a function in C, not sure where you came up with that.  The only thing you cannot truly pass to or return from a function is an array as it will decay to a pointer (which works just as well).

Comment: So I edited my originally posted code, can you guys take a look at it? It still gives me the same error